# getting php data by label name

Tags: php, jquery

I made system where code is requesting all data from database using foreach, easy right. I displayed this in table, not so hard. Now i wanna try out how to foreach all data by label name. I have 8 different labels. Ideal would be if i can check them using jquery or php

I haven't tried any methods yet, i tried to google it, maybe i did google it wrong but i did not get any answer, that's why I'm here.

getting all data from database

```php
public function guideData(){
    $ID = sanitize($_SESSION['user']);
    $guideData = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM crm_bosg"); 
    if($guideData->count()){
      $results = $guideData->results();
      $this->_results['guideData'] = $results;
    }else{
      $this->_errormsg[] = 'ohutusjuhendite aluste info puudub';
    }
    return $this;
  }
```

displaying all data in html table.

```php
<?php $guideData = $user->guideData();?>
    <?php if(!$guideData->error()){
    echo '
        <div class="danger-type row m-0 px-3 py-2 border-bottom">
            <span class="phoneview  col-xl-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-1 my-2">ID</span>
            <span class="  col-xl-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-4 my-2">Alus</span>
            <span class="col-xl-8 col-md-4 col-sm-7 col-7 my-2">tekst</span>
        </div>';
        foreach($guideData->results()['guideData'] as $gd => $gdata){ ?>
        <div class="danger-type border-bottom row m-0 px-3 py-2">
            <span class=" phoneview  col-xl-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-1 my-2"><?=$gdata['id']?></span>
            <span class="col-xl-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-4 my-2"><?=$gdata['label']?></span>
            <span class="col-xl-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-6 my-2"><?=$gdata['descs']?></span>
            <span data-toggle="modal" style="font-size: 20px;" class="hvr-icon-pop cursor-pointer"><i class="fas fa-trash hvr-icon"></i></span>
        </div>
        <?php }
         } ?>
```

I try to explain maybe better here. Basically i wanna do that when first label is "main data" and second label is "secondary data"

And then there will be 2 different table

main data- 
Here would come all data where label name is "main data"

Secondary data- 
here would come all data where label name is "secondary data"

Comment: Why all the unnecessary `?><?php` again an again

Comment: To add html between them, then i don't need use ' '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get help but i solved it myself, it was pretty easy actually. I just made if call in foreach.  And it worked fine.

```
         foreach($guideData->results()['guideData'] as $gd => $gdata){
                if($gdata['label'] == "Üldised nõuded"){?>
                    <p><?=$gdata['descs']?></p>
         <?php }?>
            <?php }
                   }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, scan the page for labels, and assign a reference to the label from the actual form elements. Here is an example:

```
var labels = document.getElementsByTagName('LABEL');
for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    if (labels[i].htmlFor != '') {
         var elem = document.getElementById(labels[i].htmlFor);
         if (elem)
            elem.label = labels[i];         
    }
}
```

Then, you can simply go:

```
document.getElementById('MyFormElem').label.innerHTML = 'Look ma this works!';
```

This codes are writen in Javascript :) I hoped it helped you a bit.

---Added Content---

If you want to include the code in your PHP file do something like that:

```
<?php
    echo("
        <script>
            var labels = document.getElementsByTagName('LABEL');
            for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
                if (labels[i].htmlFor != '') {
                     var elem = document.getElementById(labels[i].htmlFor);
                     if (elem)
                        elem.label = labels[i];         
                }
            }

            document.getElementById('MyFormElem').label.innerHTML = 'Look ma this works!';
        </script>
    ");
?>
```

Ahh and In case why are you write `?><?php` makes no sence in my eyse. You have the echo, print and print_r function in PHP which allows you something like

```
<?php
$guideData = $user->guideData();
    if(!$guideData->error()){
        echo('
        <div class="danger-type row m-0 px-3 py-2 border-bottom">
        <span class="phoneview  col-xl-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-1 my-2">ID</span>
        <span class="  col-xl-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-4 my-2">Alus</span>
        <span class="col-xl-8 col-md-4 col-sm-7 col-7 my-2">tekst</span>
        </div>');
        foreach($guideData->results()['guideData'] as $gd => $gdata){
            echo('<div class="danger-type border-bottom row m-0 px-3 py-2">
            <span class=" phoneview  col-xl-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-1 my-2">'.$gdata['id'].'</span>
            <span class="col-xl-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-4 my-2">'.$gdata['label'].'</span>
            <span class="col-xl-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-6 my-2">'.$gdata['descs'].'</span>
            <span data-toggle="modal" style="font-size: 20px;" class="hvr-icon-pop cursor-pointer"><i class="fas fa-trash hvr-icon"></i></span>
            </div>');
        }
    }
?>
```

In case of that I hope I could helped you a bit and you enjoyed the code.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I just made my script work like i wanted but I will consider using it!

Comment: no problem your answer cam 2 seconds before mine xD I added a few edits to the post I hope you can included it easier now or something like that xD